# Execute many scripts only if condition is met, without breaking IF through GO-statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd, database-project

In my SSDT Project (Visual Studio Database Project) i have a lot of scripts that must be executed **only if** a condition is met.
The condition is the servername (`@@servername != 'LiveServer'`).
The scripts will do various things like create tables/stored procedures/jobs, fetch data from elsewhere etc.
As there are many things that will be executed, there are many `GO`-statements in those scripts.

---

**The Problem:**
As there are many `GO`-statements, how do i get the condition to work? When doing it like this, i guess the `GO` statements inside those `PostDeployMasterScripts` will break the `IF`-statement?

```
IF (@@SERVERNAME != 'LiveServer')
print CONVERT(varchar, sysdatetime(), 8) + ' executing linked scripts'
:r .\PostDeployMasterScripts\Linked\CreateTemporaryTables.sql
:r .\PostDeployMasterScripts\Linked\CreateProcedures.sql
:r .\PostDeployMasterScripts\Linked\FetchInitialData.sql
:r .\PostDeployMasterScripts\Linked\CreateJobs.sql
print CONVERT(varchar, sysdatetime(), 8) + ' linked postdeploy finished'
GO
```

---

I was thinking about moving all of these postdeploy-scripts into a separate project in my solution, but i'm not sure if that would fix the issue, even if and when i find a way to only execute the scripts under the given condition.

---

**The needed solution: *(tl;dr)***
What is the best way to implement the given condition and execute my scripts and not break the `IF`-statement? (postdeploy, additional project,...?)

Answer (score 0):

Have your `IF` check in a little batch that then sets [`PARSEONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to `ON`.

Every subsequent batch will not be executed, until it hits another `SET PARSEONLY` statement (yes, the documentation doesn't actually mention that `SET` statements are exempt from the "don't compile and execute"-ness of `PARSEONLY`)

Comment: Would it be possible to get a short example, as i'm not really sure how to do that. I tested it [like this](https://i.imgur.com/q0bBqa3.png) but in this case, no tables are created. I just get the notice that the command was executed successfully.

Comment: Oh wait, you meant to `SET PARSEONLY ON` when i dont want to execute the scripts? So i flip the condition around to return true when the scripts should not be executed. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/JhnmOCx.png)?